# How to configure usage of AWS profile during amplify init?

Tags: aws-amplify

During amplify init there is a question:

> "Do you want to use AWS profile"

What is "AWS profile in this context"? When should i choose yes, and when no? What is the decision impact on the project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After installation of AWS CLI, you can configure your CLI using **aws configure** command. You provide access key, secret access key and default region. Once you are done with this it creates a default profile for your CLI. All your aws commands use credentials from this default profile. Your amplify init command refers to this profile.

You can have multiple AWS profiles for your CLI to use.

Coming to your question.

1) If your aws default profile is configured for the same account where you want your amplify project to deploy you can say yes to that question.

2) If you are not sure what is there in your default profile you can opt for no and provide access key, secret key and other information by own.

Hope this will clear your doubt.